# .tpl file and %%. Is this smarty?

Tags: smarty

I have a .tpl file which has %% variables in it.

Example:

```
%%GLOBAL_Error%%
```

Is this a smarty template engine file?

I want to check if this variable is not empty, but I can't do this with regular smarty syntax.

```
{if isset($GLOBAL_Error) }
```

How can i do this?

> I got response that this is Twig template engine :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, smarty use `{` and `}` as delimiters. So, you can write code:

```
{if $GLOBAL_Error}{/if}
```

But delimiters could be changed to `%%` and code must be in such form:

```
%%if $GLOBAL_Error%%%%/if%%
```

See also: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.escaping.tpl

Comment: Thx this works in smarty but I get response that this is Twig template engine :S

Answer (score 1):

It *might* be, but it might not be. [Smarty tag delimiters](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.left.delimiter.tpl) are configurable, so it's possible the developer set them to `%%` and `%%`. `GLOBAL_Error` may not be a variable, but a function call with no parameters. In that case, you'd need something like:

```
%%if (%%GLOBAL_Error%%) %%
```

That's some pretty ugly syntax though. It could be anything, maybe a string token for some search/replace before or after the template is compiled. If you're already using Smarty with standard delimiters, then it's unlikely that `%%GLOBAL_Error%%` is meant to be parsed by Smarty - it might even be a mistake or relic of old code. The only way to know for sure is to ask the author or just look at the codebase.